# How to add NA's to the data not available for some dates?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I have a data for short term electricity load forecasting. I have to clean the data, adding NA's in the data for dates( and blocks) with no data. 
For example: 1st case: with some dates missing:

```
         data<-data.frame(date=c("2014-01-01","2014-01-02","2014-01-04"),value=c(1,2,3))
```

Notice that `2014-01-03` is missing. So I want to add a row with this date and NA's corresponding to the columns for this date.

The required output data is:

```
        out_data<-data.frame(date=c("2014-01-01","2014-01-02","2014-01-03","2014-01-04"),value=c(1,2,NA,3))
```

2nd case: with some blocks missing from the date:

```
1,2,3,4,5,7,9,10
```

Notice that 6,8 blocks are missing. So I want to add a row for these blocks (6,8) and NA's corresponding to the columns for these blocks.

First problem is how to figure out missing dates, blocks. Once figured how to add NA's as described above. I am trying to accomplish this using loops, but if someone has a better approach or know some efficient package please help.

Edit- The software I am using is R

Thanks

Comment: First, programming questions are off-topic on CV - there are better suited on SO. Second, you didn't even mention what kind of software you are using so how could anyone help you? Third, you should provide a reproducible example so we could get better understanding of your problem.

Comment: First, Sorry, I didn't know the difference in topics entertained on SO and CV.  Second, Yes the problem is in R. Third, I tried to provide an example of the problem for better understanding. I will edit the question details with more suitable example. As of know,I suppose people with experience in load forecasting data might have understood the problem.

Comment: Look into the `_join` family from `dplyr` package.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to know without a reproducible example, but I gave it a go:

Case1

let's create some dummy data:

```
days <- c(1,2,4:6,9)
yourDates <- as.Date(paste(2014, 1, days, sep = "-"))
set.seed(111)
data <- data.frame(date= yourDates, col1 = rnorm(6), col2 = sample(letters, 6))
```

specify the last desired date:

```
enddate <- max(data$date)
```

create a new dataframe with NAs for missing dates:

```
df  <-  merge(data, data.frame(date = seq(min(yourDates),
              as.Date(enddate), 1)), all.y = T)

# if you want to replace the dates where you have no records with NA: 
df$date[!df$date %in% yourDates]  <-  NA
```

Case2

create full data based on your dates and blocks:

```
data2  <- expand.grid(block = 1:10, date = yourDates)
```

data with gaps (block 6, 8, is missing from the first date, and some other is also missing):

```
data2.gaps  <- data2[-c(6,8, 15, 29),]
# and put NAs where block is missing:
data2$block  <- data2.gaps$block[match(interaction(data2$block, data2$date), 
                                       interaction(data2.gaps$block, data2.gaps$date))]
```